# How do I hide a text box in html

Tags: html

I am a newbie in programming and I started learning programming a few days ago and I want to add a hidden text box about the browser how do I do it with thanks to everyone.

`<input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo $w2;?>"/>`

Comment: Sorry I'm new here

Comment: @radi Don't worry about it. Users are encouraged to search for similar questions before posting, but if you're new to programming, it can sometimes be hard to know what to search for. Do check out the suggested duplicates, and if one of them answers your question, you can upvote the question (because it was something you wanted to know too) and the answer that solved your problem (because it helped you) and maybe comment here to say which one it was. The upvotes help others find that answer, and the comment helps us tidy up here. Duplicates act as signposts to help others find the answer.

Comment: Thank you for being new and making me suffer a little bit but everyone here is like one family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by changing type form text to hidden 
try this 
`<input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo $w2;?>"/>`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `type="hidden"`:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo $w2;?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do, create a hidden type input

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo $w2;?>"/>
```

or hide input using css

```
.hidden{
   display:none;
} 

<input type="text" class="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo $w2;?>"/>
```

Both ways work, utilities vary from case to case, css is best used if at some point is going to show the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="3487">
```

The "type="hidden"" would hide it.

Comment: Makes the text hidden

Comment: I've meant to explain it in your answer... You can edit it anytime!

Comment: Oh okay! Will do.